# How to structure Google Datastore (App Engine) web traffic model?

Tags: google-app-engine, group-by, google-cloud-datastore

**Simple Task:**  keep track of web traffic (hits) so that I can graph the number of hits per day for the last 30 days.

Current Datastore Model (2 fields): 1) Website ID 2) Timestamp of Hit

**Problem:**  I'm using Google App Engine's datastore and don't have the ability to do a group-by or count.

Can anyone offer a simple way to structure my Google Datastore database to achieve this task?   By returning all of the hits and then grouping them in my code seems like a performance hog. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use Google Analytics?

Comment: The app needs to do this as part of something else. Not just monitoring traffic for my own benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I would use sharding counters for this specific task; have a look to the last example of [this](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) documentation.